# Nested strtok_r(): succesive tokens contain parent delimiter

Tags: c, string, parsing

A given string has key:value pairs of cities and their distances, I am using `strtok_r` to first separate using the `";"` delimiter to obtain `"city1,1223"` and nested `strtok_r` to obtain `"city1"` and `"1223"`. After the second city the nested tokens appear with the parent delimiter (`now sTok=243;city3`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_CITIES 120

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    int distance;
} location_s;

int main(void) 
{
    char *str = "city1,1223;city2,243;city3,500;city4,50";
    char *delim = ";";
    char *subDelim = ",";

    char *endStr;
    char *tok, *buf;

    location_s *loc[MAX_CITIES];

    /* Work around str* str[] conversion */
    buf = malloc(strlen(str));
    strcpy(buf, str);

    tok = strtok_r(buf, delim, &endStr);

    int tokenCount = 0, subTokenCount = 0;
    while (tok) {
        char *lastToken;
        char *sTok = strtok_r(tok, subDelim, &lastToken);
        loc[tokenCount] = (location_s*)malloc(sizeof(location_s));
        while(sTok){
            printf("now sTok=%s\n",sTok);
            if(subTokenCount == 0) loc[tokenCount]->name     = sTok;
            if(subTokenCount == 1) loc[tokenCount]->distance = atoi(sTok);

            subTokenCount++;
            sTok = strtok_r(NULL, subDelim, &lastToken);
        }
        subTokenCount = 0;
        tokenCount++;
        tok = strtok_r(NULL, "\n", &endStr);
    }

    /* Iterating through list of location */
    int minDistance = INT_MAX;
    int refPoint = 0, j = 0;
    int refDistance = minDistance - refPoint;
    char *minCity;
    for(int i=0; i < tokenCount; i++) {
        refDistance = loc[i]->distance - refPoint;
        if (refDistance < minDistance) {
            minDistance = loc[i]->distance;
            j = i;
        }
    }

    minCity = malloc(sizeof(loc[j]->name));
    strcpy(minCity, loc[j]->name);

    printf("min: %d", minDistance);
    printf("\nplace: %s", minCity);
    free(minCity);
    free(buf);

    return 0;
}
```

I am aware that `strtok` is not a viable solution since it would loose the context of the previous tokens, here is the output of the terminal.

```
$ ./a.exe
now sTok=city1
now sTok=1223
now sTok=city2
now sTok=243;city3
now sTok=500;city4
now sTok=50
min: 243
place: city2
```

Comment: BRW: `minCity = malloc(sizeof(loc[j]->name));` That is the size of a character pointer. You probably want `1+ strlen(loc[j->name)`. The same for `buf = malloc(strlen(str));
    strcpy(buf, str);` Hint: use `strdup()`

Comment: Looks like code is doing what you asked and you've got a typo in `tok = strtok_r(NULL, "\n", &endStr);` which should be `tok = strtok_r(NULL, delim, &endStr);`

Answer (score 0):

Does the job, like Chris pointed out, there is a typo

> Looks like code is doing what you asked and you've got a typo in tok = strtok_r(NULL, "\n", &endStr); which should be tok = strtok_r(NULL, delim, &endStr); - Chris Turner

the output now is as follows:

```
$ ./a.exe
now sTok=city1
now sTok=1223
now sTok=city2
now sTok=243
now sTok=city3
now sTok=500
now sTok=city4
now sTok=50
min: 50
place: city4
```